# Get the parent site URL with Regex

Tags: .net, regex, sharepoint

I know this has been asked before, but I think it is still worth asking as I want to use the .net syntax. Also , I like going through the sample / perm links.

In Office 365 Nintex I want to construct a link to a document - this is not available so I need to built it. 
{Workflow Context:Current site URL} , yields

https://domain.sharepoint.com/subsite

I just want to extract https://domain.sharepoint.com as simply as possible. I tried this expression but far too granular

```
  (?<!www\.)(?<=\.)[^\/\.]{5,}{1,2}\/
```

Comment: Try `.*(?=\/)`. It should do it for you It'll get everything up to the last `/`.

Comment: could you define "as simply as possible" please?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your prompt responses, I will test out shortly and report back. Yes 'simple; means I just want use the string operation: Replace or Check Match or Split or extract that just pulls out the string I need ; otherwise it is me having to parse an interim collection to extract my base url. I should be able to figure this out hopefully ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 .*(?=\/)
```

It'll get everything up to the last `/`
`(?=\/)` is a zero width positive look-ahead matching a following `/`, and thanks to the greedy `.*` everything up to the last one is matched.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dL7iO3/1).

Depending on what you consider simple, you could also do it with

```
(.*)\/
```

and get the result from the capture group 1.

**Edit:**

Comments suggest problems with the result being returned as a collection instead of a string. Try replacing instead. That should return a string.

This requires a different strategy though: Have the regex match anything that should be removed:

```
/[^/]*$
```

should match the last `/` and anything after it (not being a `/`). Replace that with an empty string and you should (hopefully) get the expected output.

Comment: I think `.*(?=\/)` is what OP needs as this is most probably is used with the *Extract* option. Or even `.*(?=/)` since it is a .NET regex.

Comment: @ClasG ... seems a alight quirk with the .NET syntax.  Using the Extract method on my Nintex regex espression  . here is the output log                                    SourceURL :  https://domain.sharepoint.com/subsite  
 23/08/2016 12:09 Comment 

 extracted parent domain: ["https:\/\/domain.sharepoint.com",""]  .  Note I can handle the output collection var ( you can see why I tried to avoid this tho)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I get what you mean.Is the problem that you get the result as a collection. Dunno why Nintex does that, but I think you can go around it by making a replace instead. Replace everything from the last `/`  (including) with nothing. Regex: `/[^/]*`. If I read the docs properly, it looks like replace returns a string.